# React error: Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs

I write a time count down component:

```
class CountDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const {target} = this.props
    this.state = {
      target,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const {target} = this.state
    if (target) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          target: target - 1,
        })
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
  render() {
    const {target} = this.state
    return <span>{target}</span>
  }
}
```

when run it, the develop console told me

> setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the CountDown component.`

I don't know what's wrong with my code

Comment: Is that all your code? How do you render it?

Comment: @Li357 `<CountDown target={3} />`

Comment: It's not in this block of code - Here is a [working code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7885xzxv4). Side note: You might want to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` if you want it to keep counting down. Maybe a condition to clearInterval when it's < 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that the `CountDown` component is mounted and unmounted within 1000ms. (check the component where `CountDown` is rendered)

When the `CountDown` component is mounted, `setState` is scheduled to be called after 1000ms (from `componentDidMount`). The component might have been unmounted before 1000ms. When the `setState` method gets called after 1000ms, the component is already unmounted and hence the warning.

To prevent `setTimeout` from being called after the component is unmounted, call `clearTimeout` before unmounting. (to stop the warning messages)

```
class CountDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const {target} = this.props
    this.state = {
      target,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {target} = this.state
    if (target) {
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          target: target - 1,
        })
      }, 1000)
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer)
  }

  render() {
    const {target} = this.state
    return <span>{target}</span>
  }
}
```

**PS**: You might want to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` if you want it to keep counting down as noted in the comments.